# Get args Haskell

Tags: haskell, arguments, command-line-arguments

I'm having problems with an exercise, and can not understand the error.
It should be a simple exercise with args:

```
import System.IO
import System.Environment

main= do
args < - getArgs
nomeficheiro <- return( args !! 0)
putStrnLn ( "Name is" ++ nomeficheiro)
```

Then i should run it, with : $ ./comando James

The error:

```
 <interactive>:51:1:
parse error on input ‘$’
Perhaps you intended to use TemplateHaskell
```

I've read other doubts about args at this fórum  and I didn't find any answer that could help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$ ./comando James` isn't meant to be run on GHCi. Instead, `$` at the start of the line indicates that the following line should be run in your bash/cmd/shell, **not** in GHCi:

```
# in your favourite shell, in the correct directory
./comando James
```

If you want to run `main` with arguments within GHCi, you can use `:main args`:

```
ghci> :main James
```

#### Further remarks

Your current code isn't indented correctly, so make sure that you fix this too. Also, you can use `let nomeficheiro = head args` instead of `… <- return …`. Keep in mind that this could lead to problems if one doesn't supply any argument to your program, since `head []` calls `error`.